# Authentication of mobile apps using Identity server

Tags: api, authentication, access-token, federated-identity, identityserver2

What is the reference architecture for adding authentication and authorization to a mobile application. Do I need access tokens infrastructure or can I just use validation of a token data using private-public key pair. Do I need a dedicated Identity server(like wso2 identity server) incase I also want to release a developer API.

Thanks in advnace

**Update** 
Things I have tried: I have worked on a project which uses the PKI based validation for every request(token data encrypted at client, token and encrypted data sent over to the server with every request and server decrypts to validate the client) this is a custom implementation, this I feel not the best way to do this, done some basic research to find the right way to do it. Found OpenAM and WSO2 IS, which can connect against multiple user store. They support token based authentication and policy based access control among other features.

What I'am looking for here: Am I on the right track, shall I goahead evaluating the two products, given that I also want to use the same platform another part of the same application which is web-based.

Comment: I'm not putting this as an "Answer" but wanted to point you to a helpful preso that Ping Identity recently put together that you might find helpful - https://www.pingidentity.com/en/blog/2015/07/01/bringing_single_sign-on_to_mobile_applications.html